# Las flechas de incremento personalizadas en input no funcionan! ¿Cómo recoger el valor de entrada a través de botones?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, botón, input

Al principio de mi aplicación, usando las flechas de entrada o el teclado, mis datos eran enviados sin ningún problema. Queriendo hacer la interfaz de usuario más amigable decidí ocultar las flechas del navegador e implementar botones para agregar y restar en el mismo input. Tengo en mi html los siguientes dos elementos. Uno es el input para determinar la unidad a añadir a un carro y el otro elemento es un botón que debe enviar esa información a otro componente

```
<div class='child'>
  <div class='fourth'>
    <ul class='p-0 m-0'>
      <li *ngFor='let item of product.items' class='def-number'>
        <a onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" class="minus">-</a>
        <input type='number' placeholder='0' [(ngModel)]='item.quantity' (change)='this.updateCart(item)' min='0'>
        <a onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class='plus'>+</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='child d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>
  <div class='fifth'>
    <ul class='p-0 m-0'>
      <li *ngFor='let item of product.items' style='line-height: 82px'>
        <button class='cart' (click)='addItem()'><i class='icon-addcart'></i></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

y esta es mi funcion

```
 updateCart(item, idProduct) {
    console.log(item);
    this.cart.updateItem(item);
    this.eCart.next(this.cart.getCart());
  }
```

Si modifico la cantidad del input con el teclado obtengo los datos sin ningún problema para mi función 'updateCart()'. Pero el problema viene con los botones 'plus' y 'minus' y el botón de clase 'cart', ya que no sé cómo hacer que recoja los datos de la misma manera

¿Alguien que pueda darme una idea de lo que debo hacer? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que _Angular_ no te permite agregar directamente el evento `onclick` y debería ser algo como `<a (click)="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class='plus'>+</a>`

Comment: @Triby lo he probado pero tampoco funciona, gracias de todas formas

Comment: Inspecciona los botones en el navegador para ver si aparecen correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de resolver esto puede ser asi:

Para el boton de menos:

```
(click)="item.quantity = item.quantity-1; this.updateCart(item)"
```

Para el boton de mas:

```
(click)="item.quantity = item.quantity+1; this.updateCart(item)"
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbcdt5)